# Configure CORS on a bucket, command can't find file?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cors, google-cloud-console

You might have to zoom in the picture, but I'm trying to update my bucket's CORS configuration by using the command
"gsutil cors set <CORS_JSON_FILE> gs://<BUCKET_NAME>"
but seems like it can't find my file even though it is clearly there?

```
jzhang172@cloudshell:~ (bionic-kiln-356221)$ gsutil cors set gs://portfolio-jzhang172/CORS_JSON_FILE.json gs://portfolio-jzhang172
OSError: No such file or directory.
jzhang172@cloudshell:~ (bionic-kiln-356221)$ gsutil cors set CORS_JSON_FILE.json gs://portfolio-jzhang172                                                                                                  
OSError: No such file or directory.
jzhang172@cloudshell:~ (bionic-kiln-356221)$ gsutil cors set CORS_JSON_FILE gs://portfolio-jzhang172                                                                                                       
OSError: No such file or directory.
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxcSc.jpg

Answer (score 2):

For cloudshell, you can create the file in the command line and then link to it:

Create the file:

```
echo '[{"origin": ["*"],"responseHeader": ["Content-Type"],"method": ["*"],"maxAgeSeconds": 3600}]' > cors.json
```

Add it to your bucket

```
gsutil cors set cors.json gs://<your-bucket-name>
```

If you want to use the local file you created, you can download Google Cloud SDK, then type:

`cd C:\path\to\your\json`

`gsutil cors set <cors.json> gs://<bucket-name>`

****If you are new to the SDK, when it opens run these commands first:

`gcloud auth login` and complete login in your browser

`gcloud set project <your-project-id>`

Answer (score 0):

The error **OSError: No such file or directory** means that the command is looking for the file on your local file system and not in the cloud.

> The cors-json-file specified on the command line should be a path to a local file containing a JSON document

[Reference](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cors#set)